# Tensorflow tf.layers, tf.contrib.layers not working with variable scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am beginning to use TensorFlow for some simple Q-learning, but have run into trouble when trying to use variable scopes with layers constructed using `tf.layers` and `tf.contrib.layers`. In a nutshell, I want to apply the same layers to different input tensors (for example, to hold the current and next Q values). Here is a minimal example using `tf.layers`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, (4,1))
inp2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, (4,1))

def process(inp):
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
        return tf.layers.dense(inp, 12, name="bar", reuse=True)

process(inp1)
process(inp2)
```

Trying to execute this code gives the following exception:

```
ValueError: Variable foo/bar/kernel does not exist, or was not created with
tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

I understand that setting `reuse=True` in `tf.layers.dense()` makes it try to find an already defined layer, which it may fail to do. But if I change the call into `tf.layers.dense(inp, 12, name="bar")`, then it fails with the same exception.

If I set `reuse=None` in `tf.variable_scope()`, then the latter version fails during the call of `process(inp2)` with the exception:

```
ValueError: Variable foo/bar/kernel already exists, disallowed. 
Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

Unfortunately, similar errors occur when using `tf.contrib.layers`.

My question is: Is there a way to make `tf.layers` work with variable scopes? I know that I could define the weights and biases separately, but it would be nice to retain the abstraction given by `tf.layers`. Thanks a lot!

My setup is TensorFlow 1.3.0 (CPU) running with Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10 (installed through pip on 64-bit Anaconda 4.4.0).

P.S. I found the use of variable scopes for layers on page 17 of [this presentation](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/lectures/slides_14.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors are different: the first one happened in `process(inp1)`, where it tries to find the existed variables but there is not; the second happened in `process(inp2)`, where the variable with same name existed but it tries to create a new variable with the same name, disallowed.

I guess that you want to reuse those variables for Q-learning. So the solution is quite simple: the first time you define those variables, don't use `reuse`, then you can set `reuse=True`.

In the presentation you gave, I guess they have already defined variables before.

This [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables) will help you under more.

Comment: It seems that Tensorflow now has a new feature: tf.AUTO_REUSE. This can be used instead of True and False for "reuse=", and it achieves exactly what you said before: creates the variables the first time, and reuses them later.